# Reshape images for to fit SVM classifier

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have images with this shape `(80000, 224, 224, 3)` i want to fit these images to SVM classifier but i need to reshape them , how would it do that ?

Comment: This depends entirely on the implementation of the rest of your code. You should look at the numpy reshape function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your shape `(80000, 224, 224, 3)` represents `(n_samples, pixel_width, pixel_height, n_channels)`, and assuming that you want to reshape it into a 2-D matrix of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`, the following code will help.

```
m_samples = orig_image_matrix.shape[0]
image_matrix = orig_image_matrix.reshape(m_samples, -1)
```

For the dimension with -1, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Comment: It helps, Thanks !!